# Service stops by install other applications

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I develop a mobile device manager with a service in it. I've got a strange problem under Android 4.0.3, if I install another application, my service stops.

I got no errors, I just see it when I want to open my application again. I do some searches before, but found nothing about that.

Does anyone know where does it come form, or maybe got the same problem?

Comment: Is it reproducible on some particular device only?

Comment: then only solution is to restart your Service when any new app is installed by user

Comment: I tested it with a galaxy tab 2 and a defy+, defy makes no problems. I will try it on other ics devices and post it soon

Comment: i does not happen at galaxy tab 10.1 android 3.2 and also not on a galaxy nexus with android 4.1 - i will try to test it on other devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to fix it for my case.

I start my Service with

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //some code
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The Service still crashs but this allows it to start again.